# implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' - Error

Tags: java, android

When I add implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1' then error in implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.xeoh.android:text-highlighter:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.5.0'

    implementation 'androidmads.updatehandler:updatehandler:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
}
```

Comment: `support.appcompat` is deprecated, you should [migrate to `androidx`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 0):

Play Services depend on AndroidX libraries since June 17, 2019.

You can check your options here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019

I'd recommend to migrate to AndroidX as soon as possible.